# Сортировка file input kartik

Tags: php, yii2, fileupload

Использую fileinput от Kartika в Yii2 и возник вот такой вопрос. Я выбираю фотографии, Выходит прелоад, далее и нажимаю загрузить, далее обращение в контроллер и заливка файлов но сортирует он их хаотично, ни по имени не по названию ни по размеру ни по data-fileindex. Есть возможность как то контролировать этот процесс?